# React: trigger an event or value outside the root component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-dom

Somebody could help me with this idea? I don't know if it were possible or should I use any library or skill.

**Component (This is usually and common)**

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [anyVal, setAnyVal] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Any Value: {anyVal}</h1>
      <button onClick={() => setAnyVal(anyVal + 1)}>Change value</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Connection HTML + React Dom  (This is usually and common)**

```js
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

**Here the part that I don't know if it were possible**

```html
  <body>
    <div id="root" onanyvaluechanged="externalFn(v)"></div>
    <script>
      function externalFn(newValue) {
        alert("I've detected the change:" + newValue);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
```

Comment: You'd like to add a custom event listener 'onanyvaluechanged' to a div so it fires a global function?

Comment: Thank you. Well, now you mention using a global function could be a way and the issue should be solved. But what if it was a local function?

Comment: Any function declared within the window scope will be global, so it can be accessed from to any scope. Think of any of the window (like .setInterval) or document (.querySelector) methods. A custom global function is not a good practice for most applications because creating the possibility of conflicts ie polluting the global space. A local function will be within a scope so you'd have to access it within that scope if you need to access it in the body.

Comment: Thank you guys for your help. I was researching and I found an article that talks about something similar https://medium.com/vena-engineering/how-to-use-a-react-component-in-a-backbone-view-b25d9ab39fc9   --- and here an example: https://codepen.io/lokcito/pen/yLPbjpv

Answer (score 0):

If you are declaring the function in a script tag like that, it exists in the global window scope so you can just call it like this from your react component:

```js
window.externalFn('any value')
```